Should we recommend Generative AI for fixing basic logic errors or typos in code?
I've seen a lot of questions where someone has a very basic problem, like a simple logic error or a typo. These questions often get flagged as "not reproducible" and are basically useless for other SO users.
Some of these could be fixed with a Google/SO search, of course, but it's hard to identify a typo with those types of sources. Generative AI, on the other hand, is not bad at identifying little mistakes like that and can work fairly well when presented with a typo-ridden code snippet.
Would it be reasonable to begin directing new users to AI tools for these kinds of problems? Could that cause confusion among new users over whether AI content is allowed on SO?

Current policy says no, such AI use is banned: "This includes [...] using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.". Are you proposing changing the policy?

Why are you saying "use AI"? That's generally terrible advice. For almost all languages, there are language-specific tools that are actually designed specifically to solve/find such problems and usually do an excellent job, rather than "use AI", which is, at best, a crap-shoot, and routinely terrible, causing more problems for the user. If anything other than just closing the question as a typo, you could point the user at a page that describes how to use the existing tools for the language.

kmdreko I think there's a difference between questions that can be "reworded" using AI and questions that can be solved in five seconds by posting your questions to ChatGPT instead of SO.

@Makyen That makes sense to me. I think I'm just annoyed at how many of these questions can be answered with "put the comma outside of the quotes instead of inside" or "please read your error message, it tells you everything you need to know."

I'd rather they just use one of the many enterprise-grade spellcheckers available, instead.

I think I misunderstood your post at first (vocabulary typos vs code typos causing the problem). Though I agree, even in those cases suggesting an AI is dubious.

I mean… a code editor worth using would do a better job of pointing out these kinds of problems.

Sometimes it helps. Sometimes it makes things a LOT worse, and if the asker didn't manage to spot the "trivial" mistake themselves, they're probably not going to notice when the AI takes all their base.

Why would I trust a generative AI to spot typos, when it produces hallucinations and can't reliably do arithmetic?

Or be able to tell a C snake from a Python.

@AndrewYim - " I'm just annoyed at ..." - This is why those questions do NOT meet the quality expectations, and there is a close reason for questions being caused by a typo in the author's code. Questions that do NOT meet our quality expectations should NOT be answered.

Yeah, of course. This isn’t “should we answer these questions,” it’s “how can we redirect users once their bad questions are closed.” We’ve agreed that if you want to leave a comment, you should leave a link to a debugging tutorial so they don’t need to ask these questions in the future.

There are perfectly fine services out there which provide recommendations for changes, I believe Grammarly was one. What kind of software algorithm is used behind the scenes to do that is entirely irrelevant. As long as it is still up to the person then to implement the recommendations into their own text. It really does not need to be difficult; just don't copy/paste text onto the site which came directly steamrolling out of a software algorithm. Human thought and effort needs to be involved.

Please don't do this. AI sometimes works, but it's an unsustainable way of debugging. It's much better to link to a debugging tutorial. That way, even if it takes them longer to debug their issue this time (which isn't guaranteed), they know how to read error messages or resolve their problems quicker and more reliably in the future.
